# Django password reset - Send mail using celery

Tags: django

I'm following [this](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.in/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html) blog for Django password reset. There are 2 doubts in it.

1) How can I send password recovery email as a parallel task, ie via celery? It takes a long time to proceed serially which hampers the user-experience.

2) If the user is logged-in, ie if user is authenticated, then it should **not** be redirected to the password reset urls. Currently, it does.

How can I over-ride these 2 features?

Comment: why someone has voted it as closed?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but the problem might be that you are asking about two separate problems. It might be better to ask two separate questions, and provide more details. Which specific bit are you stuck on? Have you looked at the code for the password reset view and form? Do you know how to create a celery task? Note that the blog post is for an old version of Django so bits of it are out of date (e.g. `uidb36`).

Comment: for 1 see answer below. as alasdair mentioned - this are two completely unrelated questions... as well 2) would need some more information - it is impossible to understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1. i would recommend to use [djcelery_email](https://github.com/pmclanahan/django-celery-email)

All you have to do is swap the email backend in your settings

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'djcelery_email.backends.CeleryEmailBackend'
```