# How to send Django's password reset email using Celery (without third-party package)?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, rabbitmq, celery

First of all I know this question has been answered previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263670/django-password-reset-send-mail-using-celery) which use a third-party package [django-celery-email](https://github.com/pmclanahan/django-celery-email), but I am trying to figure out how to do do such job without relaying on any third-party library.

So I need to send password reset email asynchronously with *Celery*.

My `forms.py` file look like this:

```
from django import forms
from accounts.tasks import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm as PasswordResetFormCore


class PasswordResetForm(PasswordResetFormCore):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'email',
            'placeholder': 'Email'
        }
    ))

    def send_mail(self, subject_template_name, email_template_name,
                  context, from_email, to_email, html_email_template_name=None):
        """
        This method is inherating Django's core `send_mail` method from `PasswordResetForm` class
        """
        super().send_mail(subject_template_name, email_template_name,
                  context, from_email, to_email, html_email_template_name)
```

I am trying to send mail via *Celery* from `send_mail` method of `PasswordResetForm` class. I mean calling `super().send_mail(...)` with *Celery*. I also have a `send_mail` function in my *Celery*'s `tasks.py` file, where I am trying to pass `super().send_mail` method as an argument to call it from there.

Right now my `tasks.py` file looks something like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals


@shared_task
def send_mail():
    pass
```

I am using `RabbitMQ` as message broker alongside with `Celery`

Comment: What is your **specific** question?

Comment: To be absolute specific I need to know if I can pass `super().send_mail` as an argument to `Celery's` `send_mail` and call it from there? I know I can call celery task from `PasswordResetForm` like `send_mail.delay()`, but is it possible to pass the `super().send_mail` with this  @KlausD.

Comment: No, you can not serialize functions and send them to Celery. The implementation has to be in code that is executed in Celery.

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the code of PasswordResetForm.send_mail - it's utterly trivial and actually doesn't use anything of the form itself so you can just call it as `PasswordResetForm.send_mail(None, subject, template_name, etc...)`.

Comment: Thanks @bruno desthuilliers your suggestion worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have come across with a working solution for this. Here is my solution.

I have changed `forms.py` like following

```
from django import forms
from accounts.tasks import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm as PasswordResetFormCore


class PasswordResetForm(PasswordResetFormCore):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'email',
            'placeholder': 'Email'
        }
    ))

    def send_mail(self, subject_template_name, email_template_name, context, 
                  from_email, to_email, html_email_template_name=None):
        context['user'] = context['user'].id

        send_mail.delay(subject_template_name=subject_template_name, 
                        email_template_name=email_template_name,
                        context=context, from_email=from_email, to_email=to_email,
                        html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name)
```

And the changed `tasks.py` is like following

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from accounts.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm


@shared_task
def send_mail(subject_template_name, email_template_name, context,
              from_email, to_email, html_email_template_name):
    context['user'] = User.objects.get(pk=context['user'])

    PasswordResetForm.send_mail(
        None,
        subject_template_name,
        email_template_name,
        context,
        from_email,
        to_email,
        html_email_template_name
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the previous but in a condensed way

forms.py

```py
"""users/forms.py"""
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
from users.tasks import send_reset_password_email_async

class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    """
    Extend Auth Form for adding support to Async email using Celery
    """
    # keys -> email, domain, site_name, uid, user, token, protocol
    context = args[2]
    context['user'] = context['user'].pk 
    send_reset_password_email_async.delay(*args, **kwargs)
```

tasks.py

```py
"""users/tasks.py"""
from users.models import User
from celery import shared_task
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

@shared_task
def send_reset_password_email_async(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Description
    -----------
    - User must be restore from None to object.
    - Send the reset password email as async task
    """
    # Restoring user
    context = args[2]
    context['user'] = User.objects.get(pk=context['user'])
    PasswordResetForm.send_mail(None, *args, **kwargs)
```

Finally, use the form extended at the begining
urls.py

```py
"""proj/urls.py"""
from django.urls import path, include,

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
        path(
        'password_reset/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            form_class=CustomPasswordResetForm,  # <-- async email support
            # ...
        ),
        name='password_reset'
    ),
    # ...
]
```

tested!

Comment: and where are your *args and **kwargs coming from in the CustomPasswordResetForm here :

send_reset_password_email_async.delay(*args, **kwargs)